# Lenovo 330 multiple displays

Tags: display, settings

I have a Lenovo 330 Laptop and in Win10 I run three additional monitors from a USB C hub.  Elementary only sees the laptop screen and one additional monitor.  Is there some way to find all the monitors?

Answer (score 0):

From a command prompt, run `xrandr` command. 
That will list you all your displays and supported modes, here's is my personal example:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 16384 x 16384

eDP-1 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 346mm x 194mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  59.98    59.97  
   3200x1800     59.96    59.94  
   2880x1620     59.96    59.97  
   2560x1600     59.99    59.97  
   2560x1440     59.99    59.99    59.96    59.95  
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   2048x1152     59.99    59.98    59.90    59.91  
   1920x1200     59.88    59.95  
   1920x1080     60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Afterwards, you can turn them on an off from the command line as well depending location, resolution, etc.

For instance, I have my 4k main laptop display + a DisplayPort connected (through a Thunderbolt dock) 1080p display **on the right side** of my desk. In order to accomplish this with one display being HiDPI and a normal one I have the following script:

```
xrandr --dpi 200 --fb 7680x2160 --output eDP-1 --mode 3840x2160 --output DP-1-1 --auto --scale 2x2 --pos 3840x0 --panning 3840x2160+3840+0
```

eDP-1 is laptop 4k display
DP-1-1 is FHD monitor.

Go to the [official xrandr man page](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xrandr.1.html) for more information and some examples :)

Comment: OK, I am brand new to coding like this so I'm going to have to fiddle with it.  You have two displays and when I start elementary os it recognizes two but I actually have four connected through a USB C hub.  Can I set up all four?

Comment: It should, but just for fun try plugging the USB-C HUB AFTER you log-in to eOS. Let me know how it goes.